# Why wear white for the inauguration of the Mishkan?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, moshe-rabbeinu, masecheth-avodah-zarah, tzav

Rashi (Vayikra 8:28) [quotes](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.8.28?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.8.28.1&lang2=bi) the Gemara Avoda Zara saying

> ויקטר המזבחה. מֹשֶׁה שִׁמֵּשׁ כָּל שִׁבְעַת יְמֵי הַמִּלּוּאִים
> בְּחָלוּק לָבָן (עבודה זרה ל"ד)
> — Moshe (though a non-kohen) was officiating during the seven days of
> installation [in a white garment] (Avodah Zarah 34a).

What was the reason for Moshe Rabbeinu specifically wearing a white garment during the inauguration of the Mishkan? (Is there any connection to the custom many have to wear a kittel on Pesach and Yom Kippur?)

Comment: Only Moshe yoma 4.1 if I remember

Comment: Simplest -- he's accounting for all the public funds. So no seams (where he could hide coins), and anything colorful is pricier.

Answer (score 1):

The term בגדי לבן (white garments) is not just a description of the color but a category of the priestly garments specifically worn by the High Priest on Yom Kippur for the service in the Holy of Holies as can be seen [from the mishnah in Yoma with commentary of Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.3.6?lang=bi&p2=Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Yoma.3.6.4&lang2=bi):

> They brought the High Priest to immerse a second time in the Hall of Parva, which was in the sacred area, the Temple courtyard. They spread a sheet of fine linen between him and the people in the interest of modesty. And he sanctified his hands and his feet and removed his garments. Rabbi Meir says that this was the sequence: He first removed his garments and then he sanctified his hands and his feet. He descended and immersed a second time. He ascended and dried himself. And they immediately brought him **the white garments**, in which he dressed, and he sanctified his hands and his feet.

> בגדי לבן – the priest’s undercoat (see Tractate Yoma 35b), undergarment, belt and turban that are mentioned in the Torah portion of Ahare Mot (chapter 16), for all of the inner Divine service was with them, but the outer Divine service such as the daily offerings and the Musaf offering were [offered] in golden garments which he would use the entire year, and between each change of clothing requires ritual immersion and two sanctifications of the hands and feet from the laver [for the priests in the Temple court].

So Rashi is saying that during those seven days Moshe wore clothes similar to those the High Priest wore on Yom Kippur, even though Moshe himself was not a kohein. The commentary on Rashi [Gur Aryeh](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.11b.8?lang=he&with=Kedushat%20Levi&lang2=he&p3=Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Pesachim%2C_Matzah_Ashirah.3.78&lang3=he&p4=Ben_Yehoyada_on_Taanit.11b.3&lang4=he) explains the reason:

> זהו למעלת משה, כי תמצא כי כהן גדול ביום הכפורים היה משמש לפני ולפנים בבגדי לבן בלבד, נמצא כי בגדי לבן הוא מעלה גדולה. ואף על גב דכהן הדיוט משמש בבגדי לבן, חילוק יש, כי בגדי לבן לכהן הדיוט הוא מפני דהוא משותף לכל הכהנים, אבל בגדי לבן של כהן גדול היו מיוחדים לו, ואסורים לכהן הדיוט להשתמש בו (יומא ס. ), ואפילו לשנה אחרת פסולים, שיורה שהם מיוחדים לו. ולא עוד, אלא שמיוחדים לו בזה הפעם בלבד (רש"י להלן טז, כג) , ולפיכך הוא מעלה גדולה לכהן גדול להשתמש בו. וכן במשה, היה משמש בחלוק לבן מיוחד לו. וכן אמרו בגמרא (תענית יא ע"ב) שהיה משמש בחלוק לבן שאין בו אמרא, והוא חלוק לבן מיוחד למשה, מורה על מעלת משה. כי היה לו מעלה שהוא כמו שכל פשוט בתכלית הפשיטות, ולפיכך היה משמש בחלוק לבן שאין לו אמרא, כי הלבנות מורה על הפשיטות, כי כל הגוונים הם צבע, חוץ מן הלבנות שאינו צבע, ולפיכך הוא מורה פשיטות. ומה שאין לו אמרא הוא מורה פשיטות גם כן, כי כפל האמרא בסוף הבגד אינו פשיטות, אבל בלא אמרא הוא פשוט. וראוי היה למשה רבנו עליו השלום למעלתו - שהיה כמו שכל פשוט כאשר ידוע ממעלת משה - שיהיה מדו חלוק לבן שאין לו אמרא, רק פשוט לגמרי, ואם היה לו אמרא לא היה פשוט מדו, ומדתו של משה שהוא פשוט, כי הוא שכל פשוט, ולכך היה משמש בחלוק לבן שאין לו אמרא

Basically, the Gemara to Taanis 11b says Moshe wore white priestly garments without any seams, that is, the clothes were all made of one cloth instead of separate cloths woven together. The Gur Aryeh explains that the color white and the lack of seams indicate complete simplicity, which befitted Moshe because he represented pure intellect without any contamination.

This idea is also explained by some of the [commentaries](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.11b.8?lang=he&with=Kedushat%20Levi&lang2=he&p3=Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Pesachim%2C_Matzah_Ashirah.3.78&lang3=he&p4=Ben_Yehoyada_on_Taanit.11b.3&lang4=he) to that Gemara.

As to whether it connects to wearing white at the seder, I have not seen a specific link in the commentaries, but there might be one.

[2](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.11b.8?lang=he&with=Kedushat%20Levi&lang2=he&p3=Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Pesachim%2C_Matzah_Ashirah.3.78&lang3=he&p4=Ben_Yehoyada_on_Taanit.11b.3&lang4=he): https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.8.28?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Ha**strong text**mikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.8.28.1&lang2=bi&p3=Gur_Aryeh_on_Vayikra.8.28.1&lang3=bi